# Adding a quote character in a Delphi String

Tags: sql, delphi

I am writing a SQL program in Delphi 7 and came across a problem.
If you add an SQL command you have to use `'` to indicate it is a Variable or String, but I want to build up my SQL statement because it is coming from different If statements and thus have to build it up. Therefore, I wanted to know if anyone knows a trick to add a `'` into a string.

Comment: use 4 apostrophes ''''

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/delphi.html

Comment: @Gerry Coll thanks for that website it helps a lot :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't make the same mistake like many before you and lookup parametrized queries or else you will be open for SQL injection attacks. If you need to include string constants in your query then use 2 single quotes ('') or the `QuotedStr()` function from the `SysUtils` unit.

Answer (score 1):

Try two quotes to represent one i.e. ''